# Using an array of strings to sort an array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Many StackOverflow questions on sorting arrays in Javascript, however I could not find a question for this specific use case that involves a second array.

I have the following 2 arrays. One array is the main array of data, and the other array is used to filter + sort the main array:

```js
let sortingArray = ['pts', 'ast', 'reb', 'stl']
let mainArray = [
  { key: 'stl', val1: '3', val2: 5 },
  { key: 'blk', val1: '5', val2: 1 },
  { key: 'pts', val1: '23', val2: 44 },
  { key: 'fgm', val1: '11', val2: 15 },
  { key: 'ast', val1: '13', val2: 15 },
  { key: 'reb', val1: '7', val2: 4 },
];

// Using the 2 arrays above, I am trying to create the following output
let outputArray = [
  { key: 'pts', val1: '23', val2: 44 },
  { key: 'ast', val1: '13', val2: 15 },
  { key: 'reb', val1: '7', val2: 4 },
  { key: 'stl', val1: '3', val2: 5 },
];

// My code so far
outputArray = mainArray
  .filter(row => sortingArray.includes(row.key))
  // .sort()
```

I can filter, however I am not sure how to handle this sort in the best manner. To clarify, I'd like the `mainArray` to be sorted based on the order of values in the `sortingArray`. I'm sure I could come up with an 5-10 line function that handles the sort using the `sortingArray` (via a loop of the array), however it would be great if there was a cleaner, 1-2 line arrow function I could use for this. This way, I would not have to break up the chaining of functions onto the `mainArray`.

Any thoughts or help on this would be great! I will update if I come up with an answer in the meanwhile.

**Edit:** Creating a separate-function to sort the array is quite straightforward:

```
let outputArray = [];
sortingArray.forEach(key => {
    let obj = mainArray.filter(row => row.key === key)[0];
    outputArray.push(obj);
});
```

However an arrow function would still be preferred here.

Answer (score 3):

Use maps and index

```js
sortingArray.map(y => mainArray[mainArray.map(x => x.key).indexOf(y)])
```

Comment: The filtering is not my question. My question is related to the sorting.

Comment: Is this what you need? now it will return as per your order of sortingArray

Answer (score 2):

If you have for all wanted strings an object, you could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and get the objects from the map.

```js
let sortingArray = ['pts', 'ast', 'reb', 'stl'],
    mainArray = [{ key: 'stl', val1: '3', val2: 5 }, { key: 'blk', val1: '5', val2: 1 }, { key: 'pts', val1: '23', val2: 44 }, { key: 'fgm', val1: '11', val2: 15 }, { key: 'ast', val1: '13', val2: 15 }, { key: 'reb', val1: '7', val2: 4 }],
    result = sortingArray.map(
        Map.prototype.get,
        new Map(mainArray.map(o => [o.key, o]))
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you solve the problem by inverting your operation and performing your actions on your sorting array?

```
let sortingArray = ['pts', 'ast', 'reb', 'stl']
let mainArray = [
  { key: 'stl', val1: '3', val2: 5 },
  { key: 'blk', val1: '5', val2: 1 },
  { key: 'pts', val1: '23', val2: 44 },
  { key: 'fgm', val1: '11', val2: 15 },
  { key: 'ast', val1: '13', val2: 15 },
  { key: 'reb', val1: '7', val2: 4 },
];

// Using the 2 arrays above, I am trying to create the following output
let outputArray = [
  { key: 'pts', val1: '23', val2: 44 },
  { key: 'ast', val1: '13', val2: 15 },
  { key: 'reb', val1: '7', val2: 4 },
  { key: 'stl', val1: '3', val2: 5 },
];

outputArray = sortingArray
  .map(key => mainArray.filter((row) => key === row.key))
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an `object` from the `mainArray`, and take the values from this `object`.
By doing this, you can avoid running the nested loops.

```js
let sortingArray = ['pts', 'ast', 'reb', 'stl']
let mainArray = [
  { key: 'stl', val1: '3', val2: 5 },
  { key: 'blk', val1: '5', val2: 1 },
  { key: 'pts', val1: '23', val2: 44 },
  { key: 'fgm', val1: '11', val2: 15 },
  { key: 'ast', val1: '13', val2: 15 },
  { key: 'reb', val1: '7', val2: 4 },
];

function getResultant(sortingArray, mainArray) {
  const objFromArray = mainArray.reduce((acc, item) => {
    acc[item.key] = item;
    return acc;
  }, {});
  
  return sortingArray.map(item => objFromArray[item]);

}

console.log(getResultant(sortingArray, mainArray));
```